# I have a problem with the WIFSIGNALED()/WTERMSIG() macros, after using waitpid()

Tags: c, sigterm, waitpid

In this code C i launch a program from the command line and when it is closed from a signal different from SIGTERM (signal for normal end) my code should relaunch the initial program passed from the command line. But it is not so, in fact my code never relaunchs program saying that it is properly terminated.In practice my condition"if(WTERMSIG(status)!=SIGTERM)" works bad, WHY????? :'(

This is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{   
    pid_t pid;
    int* status=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    int term;
    if(argc<2)
    {
        printf("Error: Too few arguments\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(1)
    {
    pid=fork();

    if(pid!=0) /*father*/
    {
        waitpid(pid,status,0);
        //term=WIFSIGNALED(status);
        if(WIFSIGNALED(status))
        {
            if(WTERMSIG(status)!=SIGTERM)
            {
                printf("The program %d ended abnormally:\nRelaunching...\n",pid);
                sleep(1);
            }
            else
            printf("The program %d is properly terminated...\n",pid);
            break;

        }
        else
        {
            printf("Can not read the reason for termination\n");
        }

    }
    else    /*child*/
    {
        execvp(argv[1],argv+1);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    }

    return 1;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WIFSIGNALED()` and `WTERMSIG()` macros both expect plain `int`s, not pointers to `int`s. This means that in your code, where `status` is a pointer to an int, you need to use `*status` when calling the macros, to pass them the value of the integer.

That said: why are you calling `malloc()` to allocate room for a single `int`, anyway? Just use a normal variable, and `&status` if you need a pointer to it.

Also, you should return `EXIT_SUCCESS` from `main()` on successful completion of your program, not `1`.